# Querying a specific value from a field that has more than one value in flutter from firestore

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am a complete newbie in programming altogether and this is my first question on this platform. I am writing a medical app in Flutter that works just like Uber using Firebase. I have two apps, (patients and health workers) and both share a single database. On the patient's app, there are icons representing all the medical workers. what I want to do is on the click of a specific icon, I want to fetch the specific 'user_type'(health workers specifically) and display the result on a ListView.

[image]

In the 'user-type' I have pharmacists, nurses, doctors, etc.

The code I have written is shown below.

The get function:

```
  void getDoctors() async {
    try {
      final doctors = await _firestore
          .collection('users')
          .where('user_type', isEqualTo: 'doctor')
          .getDocuments();
      for (var doctor in doctors.documents) {
        print(doctor);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Button code implemented in the scaffold:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text(
            'search',
            style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            getDoctors();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

The Output on the console is:

> I/flutter ( 3262): Instance of 'DocumentSnapshot'

If it is not possible, should I change my database structure to focus on different users? For example, a different collection for each medical worker as opposed to them coming under one collection and identified only by the 'user_type" field in the Firestore.

Answer (score 1):

In your getDoctor() function, you need to change the following

```
for (var doctor in doctors.documents) {
    print(doctor);
}
```

to

```
for (var doctor in doctors.documents) {
    print(doctor.data);
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hello, I am trying to use Geofire to query nearby users but I have not been able to. I have studied the docs and implemented every step successfully except the query. It still does not produce the expected results. I can only see myself on the map and not the stored locations of other users. Can you help?

Comment: Please post a new question then link it here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62668759/getter-error-while-using-geofire-to-query