# getter error while using Geofire to query

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query database using geoflutterfire. Everything seems to work well but when i query, i get this error: The latitude and longitudes are gotten programmatically from geolocator plugin, yet flutter throws the error below.
[image]

```
 E/flutter ( 3310): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'latitude' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 3310): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 3310): Tried calling: latitude
E/flutter ( 3310): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter ( 3310): #1      _DoctorsStreamState._animateToUser (package:firstaidpatient/serviceproviders_screen/doctors_stream.dart:296:30)
E/flutter ( 3310): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3310): #2      _DoctorsStreamState._onMapCreated.<anonymous closure> (package:firstaidpatient/serviceproviders_screen/doctors_stream.dart:268:7)
E/flutter ( 3310): #3      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1233:30)
E/flutter ( 3310): #4      _DoctorsStreamState._onMapCreated (package:firstaidpatient/serviceproviders_screen/doctors_stream.dart:267:5)
E/flutter ( 3310): #5      _GoogleMapState.onPlatformViewCreated (package:google_maps_flutter/src/google_map.dart:307:26)
E/flutter ( 3310): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3310): #6      AndroidViewController._create (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:636:15)
E/flutter ( 3310): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3310): #7      AndroidViewController.setSize (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:550:14)
E/flutter ( 3310): #8      RenderAndroidView._sizePlatformView (package:flutter/src/rendering/platform_view.dart:175:29)
E/flutter ( 3310): #9      RenderAndroidView.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/platform_view.dart:156:5)
E/flutter ( 3310): #10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1746:9)
E/flutter ( 3310): #11     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:111:13)
E/flutter ( 3310): #12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
E/flutter ( 3310): #13     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:556:15)
E/flutter ( 3310): #14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
E/flutter ( 3310): #15     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:266:13)
E/flutter ( 3310): #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
E/flutter ( 3310): #17     RenderPositionedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:394:13)
E/flutter ( 3310): #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1767:7)
E/flutter ( 3310): #19     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:11)
E/flutter ( 3310): #20     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:484:7)
E/flutter ( 3310): #21     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:240:7)
E/flutter ( 3310): #22     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:399:14)
E/flutter ( 3310): #23     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1630:7)
E/flutter ( 3310): #24     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:887:18)
E/flutter ( 3310): #25     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:402:19)
E/flutter ( 3310): #26     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:884:13)
E/flutter ( 3310): #27     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:284:5)
E/flutter ( 3310): #28     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1113:15)
E/flutter ( 3310): #29     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1052:9)
E/flutter ( 3310): #30     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:968:5)
E/flutter ( 3310): #31     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
E/flutter ( 3310): #32     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter ( 3310): #33     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
E/flutter ( 3310): #34     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:261:10)
E/flutter ( 3310): #35     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:219:3)
```

Could someone explain what the problem is? All my coordinates are correctly acquired and stored on firestore.

The query was called on initState and it gave the above error and don't produce any result on the google Map

```
 _startQuery() async {
    try {
      // Get querying phone location
      var pos = await geoLocator.getCurrentPosition();
      double userLatitude = pos.latitude;
      double userLongitude = pos.longitude;
      // get center points from users location
      GeoFirePoint center = geoflutterfire.point(
          latitude: userLatitude, longitude: userLongitude);
      stream = radius.switchMap((rad) {
        //make a firestore reference
        var ref = _firestore.collection('myLocation');
        //query data from firestore
        return geoflutterfire.collection(collectionRef: ref).within(
            center: center, radius: rad, field: 'position', strictMode: true);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: //the listener is in this method                                                                                                                           
    void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    setState(() {
      _animateToUser();
      mapController = controller;
      //start listening after map is created
      stream.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList) {
        _updateMarkers(documentList);
      });
    });
  }

Comment: Not sure if this will help but try calling the query from `addPostFrameCallback` [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50682918/13625305)

Comment: the addPostFrameCallback prevented the error but the query did not bring any result. I was thinking of something. Do you think the query is failing because GeoFire relies on real-time data to get a successful query? maybe it is because I do not have active users but mock locations stored on firebase? I can send you the whole code for the map and query section to take a closer look

Comment: Not sure about that, i haven't worked with GeoFire .

Comment: can you upload a screenshot of firebase table strcuture?

Comment: OK. I have done that. I can even give you my git repo. not a big deal

Comment: kindly take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62716609/flutter-failed-assertion-line-4138-pos-12-debuglifecyclestate-elementli